# Constructor can't find appropriate definition, and 100 other errors out of nowhere?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, bulletphysics

I'm trying to write a wrapper for Bullet physics for implementing into my game framework.

I have 3 classes, mDebugDraw is an implementation of the bullet debug drawing.

mRigidBody is a container for bullet's rigid body stuff.

World is a container for bullet's world stuff.

I have ~100 errors in visual studio, and almost all of them are coming from where I'm trying to create mRigidBodies, the errors are "cannot convert from initializer list to mRigidBody", "no appropriate constructor available", as well as weird ones like "mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string) member function is already defined or declared", which isn't a function I have implemented.

world.h contains the definitions for those three classes:

```
#pragma once
#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
#include <BulletCollision\CollisionShapes\btBoxShape.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "LinearMath\btIDebugDraw.h"
#include <vector>
#include <glm\vec3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class mDebugDraw : public btIDebugDraw
{
private:
    int debugMode;
public:
    mDebugDraw();
    virtual ~mDebugDraw();

    struct mLine
    {
        glm::vec3 from;
        glm::vec3 to;
        glm::vec3 color;

        mLine(const glm::vec3 ifrom, const glm::vec3 ito, glm::vec3 _color)
        {
            from = ifrom;
            to = ito;
            color = _color;

        }
    };

    std::vector<mLine> lines;

    struct mColor
    {
        glm::vec3 col;

        mColor(const glm::vec3 c)
        {
            col = c;
        }
    };

    std::vector<mColor> colors;

    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo[2];

    virtual void drawLine(const btVector3& from, const btVector3& to, const btVector3& color);

    virtual void drawContactPoint(const btVector3& PointOnB, const btVector3& normalOnB, btScalar distance, int lifeTime, const btVector3& color);

    virtual void draw3dText(const btVector3& location, const char* textString);

    virtual void setDebugMode(int m_debugMode);

    virtual int getDebugMode() const;

    virtual void drawTriangle(const btVector3 & a, const btVector3 & b, const btVector3 & c, const btVector3 & color, btScalar alpha) {}

    void reportErrorWarning(const char * warningString) { std::cout << "Physics debugger warning: " << warningString << std::endl; }

    std::vector<mLine> & GetLines() { return lines; }

    void draw();

    void clean();
};

class mRigidBody
{
public:
    mRigidBody(std::string name, World::shapeTypes type, glm::vec3 extent, glm::vec3 startposition);
    mRigidBody(std::string name, World::shapeTypes type, glm::vec3 extent, glm::vec3 startPosition, float mass, float friction, float restitution);
    void setPosition(glm::vec3 _position);
    void setMass(float _mass);
    void setRestitution(float _restitution);
    void setFriction(float _friction);
    std::string getName() const { return name; }
    btCollisionShape* getShape() { return mShape; }
    btRigidBody* getBody() { return rigidBody; }
    int getIndex() const { return index; }
private:
    btCollisionShape* mShape;
    btRigidBody* rigidBody;
    std::string name;
    int index;
    //btDefaultMotionState * mMotionState;
};

class World
{

protected:
    World();
public:
    enum shapeTypes
    {
        sphere,
        cube,
        capsule
    };
    static World * gameWorld();
    void init();
    btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* physicsWorld;
    std::vector<btBoxShape> hitboxes;
    mDebugDraw debugDrawer;
    void drawWireframe();
    mRigidBody* getRigidBody(std::string name) const;
    void addRigidBody(mRigidBody* _body, std::string _name);
    std::map<std::string, mRigidBody *> getMap() { return mRigidBodies; }
private:
    static World *mInstance;
    std::map<std::string, mRigidBody *> mRigidBodies;
};
```

the majority of the errors come from these two lines in world.h, where I'm defining the two constructors.

```
mRigidBody(std::string name, World::shapeTypes type, glm::vec3 extent, glm::vec3 startposition);
mRigidBody(std::string name, World::shapeTypes type, glm::vec3 extent, glm::vec3 startPosition, float mass, float friction, float restitution);
```

Here's the full list of errors.

```
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  World.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(52): error C2511: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string,World::shapeTypes,glm::vec3,glm::vec3)': overloaded member function not found in 'mRigidBody'
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(73): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(62): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(65): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'glm::tvec3<float,0>::length_type' to 'btScalar', possible loss of data
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(65): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(68): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(74): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(74): error C2512: 'btRigidBody': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  c:\repo\bustle\bullet\src\bulletdynamics\vehicle\btwheelinfo.h(17): note: see declaration of 'btRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(76): error C2671: 'mRigidBody::{ctor}': static member functions do not have 'this' pointers
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(79): error C2511: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string,World::shapeTypes,glm::vec3,glm::vec3,float,float,float)': overloaded member function not found in 'mRigidBody'
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(73): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(80): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::name'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(91): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(94): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'glm::tvec3<float,0>::length_type' to 'btScalar', possible loss of data
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(94): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(97): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(104): error C2227: left of '->calculateLocalInertia' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(106): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::mShape'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(107): error C2671: 'mRigidBody::{ctor}': static member functions do not have 'this' pointers
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(107): error C2227: left of '->rigidBody' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(108): error C2671: 'mRigidBody::{ctor}': static member functions do not have 'this' pointers
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\world.cpp(108): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'mRigidBody::name'
1>  State_Tutorial.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  State_MainMenu.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  State_Loading.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  State_Gameplay.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  State_EndRound.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\state_endround.cpp(530): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  State_BulletTest.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\state_bullettest.cpp(18): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'mRigidBody'
1>  c:\repo\bustle\src\state_bullettest.cpp(18): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\state_bullettest.cpp(18): error C2512: 'mRigidBody': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(73): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\state_bullettest.cpp(19): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'mRigidBody'
1>  c:\repo\bustle\src\state_bullettest.cpp(19): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\state_bullettest.cpp(19): error C2512: 'mRigidBody': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(73): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody'
1>  Sprite.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\sprite.cpp(167): warning C4018: '>': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  Player.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  Passenger.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  Kinematic.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  GameObject.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  GameManager.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\gamemanager.cpp(49): warning C4316: 'State_BulletTest': object allocated on the heap may not be aligned 16
1>  DisplayHandler.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  DebugManager.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  CollisionBoxes.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>  Collision.cpp
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2653: 'World': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'shapeTypes'
1>c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(76): error C2535: 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody(std::string)': member function already defined or declared
1>  c:\repo\bustle\include\world.h(75): note: see declaration of 'mRigidBody::mRigidBody'
1>c:\repo\bustle\src\collision.cpp(158): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thanks in advance for any help, I've been struggling with this for a day now.

Comment: Have you tried forward declaring `World` before the other classes?

Comment: looks like you need to learn about forward declaration and resolving circular dependencies.

Comment: `World` is declared after it is used. Move the declaration of `World` above the declaration of `mRigidBody`

Comment: @Ics they reference `mRigidBody` in `World`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution was to move World before mRigidBody and forward declare mRigidBody. I knew I was making a dumb mistake, I was too frustrated to see it!

Comment: General rule of thumb: When a compiler throws a ton of errors at you, fix the very first one.  It's probably responsible for at least half of the other errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve header include circular dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`World` is used before it's declared. In the definition of `mRigidBody`'s constructors you refer to `World::shapeTypes` but `World` is only defined later in the file. Try placing the definition of `World` before `mRigidBody`. You may need to [forward declare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration) `mRigidBody` before defining `World`.

Answer (score 1):

Insert one line before mRigidBody class definition:

```
class World;
class mRigidBody
```

Comment: This is not sufficient, `mRididBod` uses `World::shapeTypes`, not just `World`.